# How can I get 2 long numbers from a uuid?

Tags: go, uuid

I'm using this library to generate a v4 uuid:

https://github.com/satori/go.uuid

What is the most efficient way to get 2 long ints from the generated uuid?

Comment: why not just generate two random longints in the first place?

Comment: that would solve this problem for now, but longer term I'll receive generated uuids as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Bytes()` function to get the bytes and then convert to a long with `encoding/binary`. As @icza mentioned, you can also slice the UUID object directly, so you don't even need to call `Bytes()`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"
import "github.com/satori/go.uuid"

func main() {
    u1 := uuid.NewV4()
    fmt.Printf("UUIDv4: %s\n", u1)

    l1 := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(u1[:8])
    l2 := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(u1[8:])

    fmt.Printf("%x %x\n", l1, l2)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", l1, l2)
}
```

Comment: [`UUID`](https://godoc.org/github.com/satori/go.uuid#UUID) is `[16]byte`, so you can simply slice it. E.g. instead of `u1.Bytes()[:8]` use `u1[:8]`.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

func main() {
    u := uuid.NewV4()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", u)
    u1 := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(u[0:8])
    u2 := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(u[8:16])
    fmt.Printf("%x %x\n", u1, u2)
}
```

Output:

```
eb33dcfa-e439-4ff9-b366-bcd397e0852f
eb33dcfae4394ff9 b366bcd397e0852f
```